# Subsymbolic/multimedia knowledge - query, creation and reasoning? Reference request?

Tags: reference-request, logic, knowledge-representation

One can consider multimedia data as a matrix of pixels, but, of course - multimedia data contains higher-order knowledge as well. E.g. everyone can describe famous paintings in terms of colours, shapes, temper, artistic techniques and so on, only rarey one describes the painting as a matrix of pixels. So - are there scientific efforts to capture, query, create, use and generate this higher-order knowledge from multimedia data in general form?

I am aware of the different specialised efforts, like pattern recognition, feature extraction from the pictures, trend extraction from the time-series (sounds), but are there efforts of unified handling of this sort of knowledge?

There is computational creativity field with strong links to aesthetics (e.g. efforts to classify what computer artwork is or is not an art) and such general framework for subsymbolic knowledge would be very desirable addition to computational creativity.

There is universal logic research efforts in the field of symbolic knowledge, so, maybe such universal approach exist for subsymbolic knowledge as well?